# Backwards Boggle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

I came up with a fun little 1-player puzzle for myself to do when bored. Pick 5-6 words, preferably words that share a good number of letters, and try to create a Boggle board containing all of those words.

For example, with the words

- PEACH
- PAGEANT
- SHOW
- WASH
- WASPS
- SHAPES

I created the following board:

[image]

Then I experimented with some weirdly-shaped boards. For instance, I figured out how to do the same set of words on the following board:

[image]

This is problem number one, for you guys to solve. Next, I tried a star-shaped board:

[image]

This is problem number two, unsolved as of yet. I have logically determined that these words can be crammed into no fewer than 13 squares, which is exactly how many this board has. If nobody can figure this puzzle out, can anyone find a 13-square arrangement in which the words *can* be found?

Comment: I managed to put five words (length 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 each) into a 3x3 grid. EDIT: Not sure if they can actually be formed using the regular Boggle dice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "pageant" has many letters that the other words don't share, so there's just enough wiggle room to shape the result, otherwise it takes a pretty tight knot.

Answer to question 2:

> ```
>    A
>   PEG
>  SSANT
>   HCW
>    O
> ```

I was hoping to find a 13-dice solution that would fit on question one's board (14 squares), but that turned out to be quite difficult. Here's a 14-dice solution to question 1:

> ```
>  AWO
>  SHC
>  PAGT
>  SEAN
> ```

Comment: Well done! I spent such a long time on that second problem with no luck.